# High Quality Voice in Google TextToSpeech Android

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I recently work on an android app that requires the usage of TTS with spanish language, I tested Google TTS and it works very good, but I'd like to have high quality voice? another question, is it possible to have a man who talk instead of a woman?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a third party tts engine it also is owned by Amazon. https://www.ivona.com/us/

Comment: Ivona has been deprecated and replaced with https://aws.amazon.com/polly/